# C++ Create superclass for structs defined in API

Tags: c++, api, struct, interface, superclass

I have an interface for an API which I can't change.
The interface contains two structs. As they are quite similar, I would like to store instances of both structs in the same collection.

As far as I understand, I need to create a superclass for those structs so that I can add instances of both structs to the collection. But is it possible to do so without changing the interface itself?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please [edit] your post to clarify. You need to be a bit more specific. C++ has no notion of a superclass.

Comment: The short answer is "no" unless adding a superclass to the `struct`s is not considered changing the interface..

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a superclass of a class in c++, but you can use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to add both structs to a collection.

Alternatively, if you have certain variables/methods in each struct that you would like to access in the same way, you could create a new class that encapsulates both structs:

```
// structs from the API

struct A {
    int some_int;
    string some_string;
};

struct B {
    int some_int;
    string some_string;
}

// new struct that you write
struct ABInterface {
    int some_int;
    string some_string;

    // "copy" constructor from A object
    ABInterface(A a) {
        some_int = a.some_int;
        some_string = a.some_string;
    }

    // "copy" constructor from B object
    ABInterface(B b) {
        some_int = b.some_int;
        some_string = b.some_string;
    }
}
```